# Apply a lambda with a shift function in python pandas were some null elements are to be replaced

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to do the following in a dataframe.
Change the Value of Column Attrition if the Period is not 1, then multiple the value of the retention column in that row by the attrition value in the row above within the groupby. My attempt is below:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country': ['DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'FR', 'FR', 'FR'],
    'Week': ['201426', '201426', '201426', '201426', '201425', '201425', '201426', '201426', '201426'],
    'Period': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'Attrition': [0.5,'' ,'' ,0.85 ,0.865,'' ,0.74 ,'','' ],
    'Retention': [0.95,0.85,0.94,0.85,0.97,0.93,0.97,0.93,0.94]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Country', 'Week', 'Period', 'Attrition','Retention'])
print df
```

## Gives me this output:

```
  Country    Week  Period Attrition  Retention
0      DE  201426       1       0.5       0.95
1      DE  201426       2                 0.85
2      DE  201426       3                 0.94
3      US  201426       1      0.85       0.85
4      US  201425       1     0.865       0.97
5      US  201425       2                 0.93
6      FR  201426       1      0.74       0.97
7      FR  201426       2                 0.93
8      FR  201426       3                 0.94
```

The below:

```
df['Attrition'] = df.groupby(['Country','Week']).apply(lambda x: x.Attrition.shift(1)*x['Retention'] if x.Period != 1 else x.Attrition)

print df
```

## gives me this error:

```
df['Attrition'] = df.groupby(['Country','Week']).apply(lambda x: x.Attrition.shift(1)*x['Retention'] if x.Period != 1 else x.Attrition)
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

**UPDATE: Complete Compiled Solution**

The below is the complete working solution of what i was after which was basically using Primer's answer but adding a while loop to keep running the Lambda function on the dataframe column until there are no more NaNs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Country': ['DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'FR', 'FR', 'FR'],
    'Week': ['201426', '201426', '201426', '201426', '201425', '201425', '201426', '201426', '201426'],
    'Period': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
    'Attrition': [0.5, '' ,'' ,0.85 ,0.865,'' ,0.74 ,'','' ],
    'Retention': [0.95,0.85,0.94,0.85,0.97,0.93,0.97,0.93,0.94]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Country', 'Week', 'Period', 'Attrition','Retention'])
print df
```

**OUTPUT: Starting DF**

```
  Country    Week  Period Attrition  Retention
0      DE  201426       1       0.5       0.95
1      DE  201426       2                 0.85
2      DE  201426       3                 0.94
3      US  201426       1      0.85       0.85
4      US  201425       1     0.865       0.97
5      US  201425       2                 0.93
6      FR  201426       1      0.74       0.97
7      FR  201426       2                 0.93
8      FR  201426       3                 0.94
```

**Solution:**

```
#Replaces empty string with NaNs
df['Attrition'] = df['Attrition'].replace('', np.nan)

#Stores a count of the number of null or NaNs in the column.
ContainsNaN = df['Attrition'].isnull().sum()

#run the loop while there are some NaNs in the column.
while ContainsNaN > 0:    
    df['Attrition'] = df.groupby(['Country','Week']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where((x.Period != 1), x.Attrition.shift() * x['Retention'], x.Attrition)))        
    ContainsNaN = df['Attrition'].isnull().sum()

print df
```

**OUTPUT: Result**

```
  Country    Week  Period Attrition  Retention
0      DE  201426       1       0.5       0.95
1      DE  201426       2     0.425       0.85
2      DE  201426       3    0.3995       0.94
3      US  201426       1      0.85       0.85
4      US  201425       1     0.865       0.97
5      US  201425       2   0.80445       0.93
6      FR  201426       1      0.74       0.97
7      FR  201426       2    0.6882       0.93
8      FR  201426       3  0.646908       0.94
```

Comment: Actually, just as a followup to this. The code above was working fine and problem solved. Then I adapted it to my more complex problem and I started getting an error, Now even this code above doesnt run. this the error i got for line 22. "raise TypeError('incompatible index of inserted column ' My pandas version is 0.15.2 I had 0.12 but read there was some issues, so upgraded to 0.15.2 but it didnt fix the problem.
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index" I also using Python 2.7.5 | Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit) and the Spyder interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your `Attrition` column mixes numeric data with empty strings `''`, which is generally not a good idea and should be fixed before attempting calculations on this column:

```
df.loc[df['Attrition'] == '', 'Attrition'] = pd.np.nan
df['Attrition'] = df.Attrition.astype('float')
```

The Error you get is because your condition in `.apply`: `x.Period != 1` produces a Boolean array:

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: Period, dtype: bool
```

Which `.apply` does not know how to handle, because of its ambiguity (i.e what should be True in this case?).

You might consider [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this task:

```
import numpy as np
g = df.groupby(['Country','Week'], as_index=0, group_keys=0)
df['Attrition'] = g.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where((x.Period != 1), x.Attrition.shift() * x['Retention'], x.Attrition)).fillna(method='ffill')).values
df
```

yielding:

```
  Country    Week  Period  Attrition  Retention
0      DE  201426       1      0.500       0.95
1      DE  201426       2      0.425       0.85
2      DE  201426       3      0.425       0.94
3      US  201426       1      0.740       0.85
4      US  201425       1      0.688       0.97
5      US  201425       2      0.688       0.93
6      FR  201426       1      0.865       0.97
7      FR  201426       2      0.804       0.93
8      FR  201426       3      0.850       0.94
```

Note that I have added `.fillna` method, which fills `NaN` with last observed value.

Comment: Thanks Primer, I am just going through your response one by one. Thanks for clarifying the issue with the empty string. I didn't quite understand how this line was working 'df.loc[df['Attrition'] == '', 'Attrition'] = pd.np.nan' I managed to find an example that was simpler for me to work with i.e. 'df['Attrition'] = df['Attrition'].replace('', np.nan)' this also seems to work. do you see any issues with this method.

Comment: The x.Period != 1 Boolean makes sense for me now thanks.

Comment: for the last part, in row 2 period 3 I was hoping this would also subsequently be filled with the same formula i.e. period 2(0.425) x 0.94. I am guessing I would need to step through each row or repeat the lambda until there are no more NaNs? I was assuming a lambda function would automatically apply the function in a sort of iterrows fashion.

Comment: I see no problem with using `.replace` to fill in `NaN`s in this example. Your original question did not specify anything about filling `NaN`s after applying the desired calculation, hence there there was nothing done about that. To address this issue I have slightly modified the answer - adding `.fillna()` method in the `.apply` part). Hope this answers the question.

Comment: Actually I dont want to fill NaN, I wanted each Period to have the Attrition.shift(1) x Retention formula applied except for the 1st period. Your original repsonse only filled the first NaN or Empty string with the calculation. I actually have 52 periods in each groupby in my real data and I need all of them to have the calculation applied. I think this lambda though wouldnt work in this case unless i stepped through the groupby rows. in my comment above I meant i wanted period 3 in row 2 to be 0.435 x 0.94. not a ffill of period 2.

Comment: Primer thanks for all your responses I am marking you as answered as I def can work with your input to finalise my problem, I just wasn't able to articulate my question 100% clear. thanks for your patience.